# Count values from selected rows from dataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, .net-3.5

I am trying to create a dataGridView which has 2 columns, column 1 contains names, and column 2 contains numbers, which is working fine.

I now want to allow the user to select a single or multiple rows using the keyboard or mouse which should automatically total up the numbers column based on the rows selected.

I so far have the following:

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.SelectedCells.Count > 0)
        {
            int selectedrowindex = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;

            DataGridViewRow selectedRow = dataGridView1.Rows[selectedrowindex];

            string a = Convert.ToString(selectedRow.Cells[0].Value);
        }
    }
```

Where `string a` will eventually show the total in a label on the form.

But this seems to be the wrong way to go about doing what I am trying to achieve.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Your code only shows the current cell? You want a **total sum** of selected numbers instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to find a total of a particular column of selected **rows**' value:

```
int total = dgv.SelectedRows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Sum(
    row => (int) row.Cells[colSomeNumber.Name].Value);
```

If you want to find a total of selected cells' values:

```
int total = dgv.SelectedCells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>().Sum(cell => (int) cell.Value);
```

If you want to find a total of selected cells' values for only some column(s), do it like this:

```
int total = dgv.SelectedCells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>().Where(
    c => c.OwningColumn == colSomeNumber).Sum(cell => (int) cell.Value);
```

Where `colSomeNumber` is the *actual* column.

Just put it in the `dgv_SelectionChanged` event and that's it. That's pretty much the "neatest" way to do it.

Comment: That does work, but only if I click on the actual content within the cells.  How do I get it to work if any part of a row is clicked to select it?

Comment: It currently looks like this: `this.dataGridView1.CellContentClick += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.dataGridView1_CellContentClick);`  Can't seem to change that the `_SelectionChanged`.

Comment: [SelectionChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) is another event, probably more suitable for what you need. If you want it to fire on selected *rows* I recommend you change the SelectionMode, e.g. `.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;` and use the first solution from the answer (user will still be able to edit individual cells).